Antlr 4 Grammar seems to ignore defined precedence
I'm having an issue with my Antlr 4 grammar, where it seems like its ignoring precedence.
For the given expression $(USD)100'2 * -1, I expect it to evaluate $(USD)100'2 first then multiply by -1.  So something like this is what I expect:

However Im getting the following:

In my grammar Im defining finAmount and numberLiteral rules before multiplication rule.  Seems like that precedence is being ignored.  Here's my grammar:
grammar tst;

root
    : expression EOF;   

expression
    : '$' currencyExpression? expression ('\'' expression)?     #expressionFinAmount
    | numberLiteral                                             #expressionNonOverloaded04
    | stringLiteral                                             #expressionNonOverloaded05
    | trueLiteral                                               #expressionNonOverloaded08
    | falseLiteral                                              #expressionNonOverloaded09
    | '(' expression ')'                                        #expresionParen 
    | expression op=(MUL|DIV) expression                        #expressionMulDiv
    | expression ADD expression                                 #expressionAdd          
    | expression SUB expression                                 #expressionSub              
    | expression op=(
                    BIGGER|
                    BIGGER_OR_EQUAL|
                    SMALLER|
                    SMALLER_OR_EQUAL) 
                    expression                                  #expressionCompare          
    | expression op=(EQUAL|NOT_EQUAL) expression                #expressionEquals           
    | expression op=(AND | OR) expression                       #expressionLogical      
    ;
        

trueLiteral
    : TRUE
    ;
    
falseLiteral
    : FALSE
    ;

numberLiteral
    : floatLiteral          
    | wholeLiteral          
    ;
    
floatLiteral
    : FLOATNUM
    ;
    
wholeLiteral
    : WHOLENUM
    ;

stringLiteral
    : STRING
    ;
    
currencyExpression
    : '('expression')'  
    | CURRENCY_LIT      
    ;


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-- Lexical Rules
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

STRING:             '"' .*? '"';

AND:                'and';
OR:                 'or';

NOT:                'not';      

TRUE:               'true';
FALSE:              'false';

FLOATNUM:           '-'? DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+;
            
WHOLENUM:           '-'? DIGIT+;
    
NULL:               'null';

MUL :               '*';
DIV :               '/';
ADD :               '+';
SUB :               '-';

BIGGER:             '>';
BIGGER_OR_EQUAL:    '>=';
SMALLER:            '<';
SMALLER_OR_EQUAL:   '<=';
EQUAL:              '==';
NOT_EQUAL:          '!=';

EQUALASSIGN:        '=';

CURRENCY_LIT:       '(' [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] ')'|
                    '(' [0-9][0-9][0-9] ')';

IDENTIFIER:         IDENTIFIERSTART IDENTIFIERPART*;

WS :                [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);  // toss out whitespace


fragment DIGIT:     [0-9];
fragment IDENTIFIERSTART: 
                    [a-zA-Z];
fragment IDENTIFIERPART:
                    [a-zA-Z0-9_];

Anybody has any thoughts?  Why is my expression not evaluating as $(USD)100'2 * -1

The reason is that you cannot use finAmout. Unfold finAmount into expression (i.e., insert the right-hand side of finAmout into where it is used in expression), and delete finAmount. You cannot "hide" the expression for finAmount. Put a # finAmount on that alt. Delete the rule for finAmount as it is now useless. Also, please use https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr-format. This is terrible formatting. Also, you must use an EOF-terminated start rule: root: expression EOF;. Also, the grammar is ambiguous.

Thanks @kaby76 I've updated the format, and moved the finAmount rule in the expression rule, but still the same results.

Then you'll have to do something like this: e: '$' currencyExpression? e | e '\'' e | e op = (MUL | DIV) e | e ADD e | e SUB e | e op = ( BIGGER | BIGGER_OR_EQUAL | SMALLER | SMALLER_OR_EQUAL ) e | e op = (EQUAL | NOT_EQUAL) e | e op = (AND | OR) e | numberLiteral | stringLiteral | trueLiteral | falseLiteral | '(' e ')';.

Looks like its related to using a sub-rule ('\'' expression):
'$' currencyExpression? expression ('\'' expression)?
If I change the expression grammar to:
expression
    : '$' currencyExpression? expression'\''expression      #finAmountWithNB10
    | '$' currencyExpression? expression                    #finAmount 

It's now parsing the way I want:

